Show that $ \mathbb{Z}_{(p)} / J $ is isomorphic to the integers modulo $ p $.
Consider $ \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ and its maximal ideal $ (p)$ for some prime number $ p $. Show that $ \mathbb{Z}_{(p)} / J $ is isomorphic to the integers modulo $ p $.
In my solution manual, the desired isomorphism from $ \mathbb{Z}_{(p)} / J $ to $ \mathbb{Z} / p\mathbb{Z} $ is defined by $ \varphi \left( \frac{i}{n}+J \right) = i \pmod{p} $, where $ n $ is any fixed integer coprime to $ p $. However, I am uncertain how defining $ \varphi $ in this way would work for elements like $ \frac{a}{b} + J $, where $ b \neq i $.
To phrase it differently, how can i show that the function is well-defined, a homomorphism and injective.
Edit: didn't realise I did not define $J$, $J=(p)$, the ideal generated by $p$

what does $J$ stand for?

You never told us what $J$ is.  Did you mean $J = p\mathbb Z_{(p)}$? I will assume so.
Are you trying to show they are isomorphic as rings? Then the suggestion in the solution manual is wrong since it will not be multiplicative. Try looking at an actual example, say with $p = 5$ and $n = 2$.
Anyway, I think it is simpler to seek a ring isomorphism in the direction $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z_{(p)}/p\mathbb Z_{(p)}$. Do you see a natural mapping in that direction?fff
